# How to access Google Maps marker data stored in marker.userData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker, gmsplace

I am currently trying to dynamically display data in a Google Maps markerInfoWindow about it's specific location using the marker.userData property.

This is my function that sets marker.userData and puts markers on my map instance:

```
func putPlaces(places: [Place]) {
        for place in places.prefix(10) {
            print("*******NEW PLACE********")
            let name = place.name
            let address = place.address
            let location = ("lat: \(place.geometry.location.latitude), lng: \(place.geometry.location.longitude)")
            let locLat = place.geometry.location.latitude
            let locLon = place.geometry.location.longitude
            let place_id = place.place_id
            let photo = place.photos
            let types = place.types

            let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locLat, longitude: locLon)
            marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .black)

            print("PLACE: \(place)")
            print("PLACE.NAME: \(place.name)")
            marker.userData = ["name" : "names"]
            marker.map = self.mapView
         }
     }
```

I can see the specific place.name printed here^^^

This is my function (copied from GoogleMapsAPI documentation) where I am trying to access elements of the data in marker.userData:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        print("Showing marker infowindow")
        print("marker.userData: \(marker.userData)")
//      error here!vvv
//      print("marker.userData.name: \(marker.userData.name)")
//      here I will pass this data to a swiftUI view that will display the data within marker.userData
        let mInfoWindow = UIHostingController(rootView: MarkerInfoWindow())
        mInfoWindow.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 48, height: 80)
        return mInfoWindow.view
    }
```

This is the data im storing in marker.userData (taken from console when marker.userData is printed):

```
Optional(GMapProj.Place(geometry: GMapProj.Place.Location(location: GMapProj.Place.Location.LatLong(latitude: 42.3405476, longitude: -71.1465262)), name: "Boston Management Office", place_id: "ChIJpYqcF01444kRO8JeAqK2NuE", openingHours: Optional(GMapProj.Place.OpenNow(isOpen: false)), photos: nil, types: ["real_estate_agency", "point_of_interest", "establishment"], address: "113 Kilsyth Road # B, Brighton"))
```

In the last function above I try to print out the 'name' element within marker.userData, but I keep getting an error saying 'Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'name'. But i can access the name when printing right before i put the data in marker.userData...

Anyone know how I can access the data stored in marker.userData and read it's elements??

Comment: By type casting you will acheive stored marker data as below.
let userInfo = marker.userData as? [String:String]
print("marker.userData: \(userInfo["name"])")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`marker.userData` type is Any?.  You can't use dot syntax on an object of type Any like that.  You need to typecast `marker.userData` to a dictionary, then access the value.  Something like this.

```
let userData = marker.userData as? [String:String]
print("marker.userData.name": \(userData["name"])
```